# Getting an error after using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to react. I'm working on developing my react project. My react components are working fine. When i install react router and use it in app.js i got some error and my webpage got blank! But when i remove react router from app.js page my web page works fine. I don't understand why this happening. Error code are below. It will be helpful if anyone has the solution.

Error code:

```
react-dom.development.js:26874 Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (router.ts:5:1)
    at useHref (hooks.tsx:32:1)
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:267:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:20023:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22465:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27381:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26390:1)
```

Here is my code:

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/Home/Home/Home';
import Header from './components/shared/Header/Header';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Inventory from './components/pages/Inventory/Inventory';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path='/inventory' element={<Inventory></Inventory>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide some code of your implementation to ba able to reproduce your error.

Comment: Please add your code for any exapmle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I think all you need is to replace `<Routes>` with `<BrowserRouter>`. You might have to add a `<Switch>` too.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path='/inventory' element={<Inventory></Inventory>}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: Hi, i just edited.. forget my  explanation. You might need it one day but maybe not today. hehe

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `react-router-dom@6` doesn't export a `Switch` component, and the `Routes` component is still required to wrap the `Route` components so route matching and rendering works.

Comment: It looks like `Switch` was replaced with `Routes` in `react-router-dom-6`. My answer is not  wrong, just dated for `react-router-dom@5`

Comment: Then this answer is still incorrect since the `react-router-dom@5` `Route` component doesn't take an `element` prop. The `element` is a RRDv6 prop and replaced the `component`, and `render` and `children` function props from v5.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

> `Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

This error is informing you that you are attempting to use some `react-router-dom` functionality *outside* of any routing context provided by a router. In other words, your app appears to be missing any router component to provide the routing context to the various `Link`, `Routes`, and `Route` components it is rendering.

## Solution

Render the app code within a router.

Example:

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/Home/Home/Home';
import Header from './components/shared/Header/Header';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, // <-- (1) import router
  Route,
  Routes
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Inventory from './components/pages/Inventory/Inventory';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router> // <-- (2) render router around app code
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/inventory' element={<Inventory />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```